# Why does wmplayer.exe start when I plug in a USB drive?

Tags: windows-vista, usb, windows-media-player

I'm using Vista.  Sometimes (but not always) when I plug in a USB drive, wmplayer.exe starts executing and apparently searching the drive for something.  I then have to kill it with Task Manager or else it won't let me remove the drive with "Safely Remove Hardware".  I only have data on this drive, and I've already disabled AutoPlay, but there must be some configuration thingy somewhere that tells Windows to start wmplayer when it detects a USB drive, but I haven't found out what.  Any ideas?  (It's an HP machine, if that makes a difference.)

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like its scanning the device to see if it can\should be synched.

you can disable it on a per-drive basis by plugging in the device, and then in Windows Media Player, go to `Tools -> Options -> Devices`. 
Double click the USB device, and uncheck `Start Synch when device connects`. Click `OK` to exit.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-pictures/how-to-stop-window-media-player-from-scanning-usb/8e1e268c-81d3-4b3b-9096-45d192236910

Comment: There's no "Tools" that I can see.  I tried the arrow under Sync -> More Options, which brought up Devices; I double-clicked on `J:/` [with a backslash], and I saw a `Start sync when device connects`, but it was already unchecked and moreover was disabled so that I couldn't have checked it if I wanted to.  It's strange.  This time, when I plugged the USB in, WMP did *not* start automatically.  Yesterday, it did it twice.

Comment: Can you check/uncheck `Create folder hierarchy on device`? Changing this or any other setting in Sync Options should cause WMP to create a `WMPInfo.xml`file in the root of the drive. The presence of such a file should prevent WMP from automatically scanning the drive next time.